# how to echo multiple lines with carriage returns

Tags: php

I am writing a web app in php to generate the commands to input into some telecom devices.  The output I get doesn't have any carriage returns on it.  How can I add the returns, just like my code below?  FYI this is just a sample commands.  The actual commands has a lot more lines.

```
<?php

echo <<<EOL
##############################################################################
#
# CLI Commands Series Base System Configuration
#   SBC Type: 
#   SBC System Name: 
#   SBC Location: 
#
# History:
# Initial Configuration Draft
#
##############################################################################

set complete-on-space false
set ignore-leading-space true

configure
set system admin DFWSBC01 contact "Me " location "Somewhere"
commit`enter code here`


# Configure Logical Management interface if not configured initially
##############################################################################
set system logicalMgmtIpInterface MANAGEMENT_LOGICAL mgmtIpInterfaceGroupName mgmtGroup ipAddress 172.17.1.10
commit
set system logicalMgmtIpInterface MANAGEMENT_LOGICAL mgmtIpInterfaceGroupName mgmtGroup state enabled
commit


# Configure Address Contexts
##############################################################################
set addressContext default
commit


# Configure IP Interface Groups
##############################################################################
set addressContext default ipInterfaceGroup INTERNAL1_IPIG
set addressContext default ipInterfaceGroup EXTERNAL1_IPIG
commit


# Configure Media Interfaces
##############################################################################

set addressContext default ipInterfaceGroup INTERNAL1_IPIG ipInterface IPIF2 ceName DFWSBC01a portName pkt2 ipAddress 4.4.4.4 prefix 27 mode inservice  state enabled 
set addressContext default ipInterfaceGroup INTERNAL1_IPIG ipInterface IPIF3 ceName DFWSBC01a portName pkt3 ipAddress 5.5.5.5 prefix 27 mode inservice state en 
set addressContext default ipInterfaceGroup EXTERNAL1_IPIG ipInterface IPIF0 ceName DFWSBC01a portName pkt0 ipAddress 36.36.36.36 prefix 27 mode inservice state enabled   (where I took over)

set addressContext default ipInterfaceGroup EXTERNAL1_IPIG ipInterface IPIF1 ceName DFWSBC01a portName pkt1 ipAddress 37.37.37.37 prefix 27 mode inservice state enable 
commit

EOL;
?>
```

Comment: Where are you displaying that string where you see it with no returns? The returns should be there. Possibly the output format/device is ignoring them.

Comment: Just to check, does the device expect \r\n for each line, does the code currently only pass \n?

Comment: Oh yeah, good point @NigelRen. I guess the returns probably _aren't_ there, actually.

Comment: @user If you're trying to view this in a browser, the browser will try to display it as HTML unless you instruct it otherwise, where any amount of whitespace will be rendered as a single space. You can output it as plain text instead by sending a content type header.

Comment: Also look at `nl2br`.

Comment: You probably just need to add `\r` to the end of every line

Comment: I am displaying this to a browser.  I know that if I do \r at the end of each line then it will work, but it is a  few hundred lines and I dont want to type an \r for each line.  Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple possibility is to just replace the newlines with newline+carriage return before outputting the text.

```
$text = <<<EOL
##############################################################################
#
# CLI Commands Series Base System Configuration

...
... more text ...
...

commit

EOL;

echo str_replace("\n", "\n\r", $text);
```

Maybe I'm oversimplifying it, but it seems like that should work.